# Rewrite ExpressJS Function to AWS Lambda (Multipart-Uploader)

Tags: node.js, express, lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

Does someone have an idea, how to rewrite this Express.js function to AWS Lambda for Node.js 18?

```
const upload = multer()

// Receive chunk and write it to S3 bucket
app.post('/upload', upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  const { index, fileName } = req.body;
  const file = req.file;
 
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: fileName,
    Body: file.buffer,
    PartNumber: Number(index) + 1,
    UploadId: req.query.uploadId
  };

  s3.uploadPart(s3Params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Error uploading chunk' });
    }

    return res.json({ success: true, message: 'Chunk uploaded successfully' });
  });
});
```

A Lambda function starts with:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use base64 string instead of multipart it is easy in AWS Lambda

If you want multipart then we can create express js app in lambda function. below are example
app.js

```
const upload = multer()

// Receive chunk and write it to S3 bucket
app.post('/upload', upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  const { index, fileName } = req.body;
  const file = req.file;
 
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: fileName,
    Body: file.buffer,
    PartNumber: Number(index) + 1,
    UploadId: req.query.uploadId
  };

  s3.uploadPart(s3Params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Error uploading chunk' });
    }

    return res.json({ success: true, message: 'Chunk uploaded successfully' });
  });
});
```

in lambda function

```
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const app = require('./app.js');
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app)

module.exports.handler = (event, context) => awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
```